# Get ul li values, like first, previous, current, next and last

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I need help to get the first, previous, current, next and last values of an ul li list...

Here is a small jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ptCoder/CCD29/

I have tried something like this (for next value):

```
alert($('#selectId li').next());
```

... but don't work. I have tried searching here, but don't have find a solution...

Can anyone help me?

Thank You.

Comment: dou you wish to get the next _list_ or the next _item_ in the currently selected list_ ? in the latter case, what qualifies for the current element (or do you need to access the respective value for each list item? in this case you may iterate over all li elements of a ul setting up individual event handlers or augment the  elments with a data-attribute specifying the position among siblings)

Comment: List items shouldn't have a value like form inputs do. While `val()` may work, it's not semantically correct and may not work in all browsers. Use `data-value="xx"` and `.data('value')` instead.

Comment: Thank You for all the replies. Problem solved...

Comment: I agree with @Blazemonger .. since your html contains a value attribute, .val() may be valid in your case but its better to use a custom attribute with 'li's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/CCD29/4/

```
$("#selectId li a").click(function () {
    $("#idValue").val(parseFloat(($(this).text())));
});

// First
$("#btnFirst").click(function () {
    alert($("#selectId li:first").val());
});

// Previous
$("#btnPrevious").click(function () {
    var currentVal = $("#idValue").val();
    var prev = $("#selectId li[value='" + currentVal + "']").prev();
    if (prev.length > 0) alert(prev.val());
});

// Current
$("#btnCurrent").click(function () {
    alert($("#idValue").val());
});

// Next
$("#btnNext").click(function () {
    var currentVal = $("#idValue").val();
    var next = $("#selectId li[value='" + currentVal + "']").next();
    if (next.length > 0) alert(next.val());
});    

// Last
$("#btnLast").click(function () {
    alert($("#selectId li:last").val());
});
```

By the way, `value` attribute for the `li` may work (code above shows), but you should not use that (Blazemonger pointed out why in the comment). You should use `data-value` instead. The fiddle using `data-value` is here: http://jsfiddle.net/CCD29/5/

Comment: Read Blazemonger's comment above about value attributes in list elements. You could fix this by getting the text of the list element.

Comment: Updated the fiddle to reflect the comment. `data-value` was used instead

Answer (score 2):

```
$('li').first().val()

$('li').last().val()
```

for First & Last 'li' values ..

For next & previous you need a reference 'li' element for that

Answer (score 2):

Try this for first and last:

```
 alert($('ul#selectId li:first').val());
 alert($('ul#selectId li:last').val());
```